# What is `type_info::before` useful for?

Tags: c++, rtti, typeinfo

According to cplusplus.com, the [`std::type_info::before()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/typeinfo/type_info/) function...

> Returns true if the type precedes the type of *rhs* in the collation order.
>   The collation order is just an internal order kept by a particular implementation and is not necessarily related to inheritance relations or declaring order.

So what is it useful for?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Consider you want to put your `type_info` objects as keys into a `map<type_info*, value>`. The `type_info` doesn't have an `operator <` defined, so you must provide your own comparator. The only thing that is guaranteed to work from the `type_info` interface is the `before()` function, since neither the addresses of `type_info` nor the `name()` must be unique:

```
struct compare {
    bool operator ()(const type_info* a, const type_info* b) const {
        return a->before(*b);
    }
};

std::map<const type_info*, std::string, compare> m;

void f() {
    m[&typeid(int)] = "Hello world";
}
```

Comment: "*The `type_info` doesn't have an `operator <` defined, so you must provide your own comparator.*" `std::less<>` (`std::map<>`'s default comparitor) works for **all** pointers, you just get address ordering instead of collation ordering.

Comment: @ildjarn: you misunderstand the problem. The standard doesn't guarantee that at most one `type_info` per type exists. Infact it's common to encounter *more than one `typeinfo`* created for the same type. The most trivial case is in context of dynamically-linked libraries, like Dietmar said.

Comment: @ildjarn Reread your quotation. It talks about `operator <` of `type_info`, but you argue about validity of comparing pointers to `type_info`, implying that the quoted sentence is somehow wrong. But it is not, because I did not say anything about comparing pointers. Then why you people write irrelevant comments?

Comment: I don't understand what `&typeid(type)` does. It obtains the address of the object `typeid(int)` in this example? But what then is `typeid(int)` - I assumed this would return an integer, like `sizeof`, but this doesn't seem to make sense when then taking the address of that object... Could you perhaps add some explanation of what this line of code in the example does?

Comment: @user3728501: it returns a statically allocated object of type `type_info`.

Answer (score 8):

This is useful to define an order on typeinfo objects, e.g. to put them into a std::map. The obvious follow-up question is: why isn't it spelled operator<()? I don't know the answer to this question.

Comment: "*The obvious follow-up question is: why isn't it spelled operator<()?*" How would one define an `operator <` for a pointer type?

Comment: `type_info` has no copy constructor or copy-assignment operator, so it can't be stored directly into a container. And of course, the key type of an associative container cannot be a reference, so the only remaining option is to store a `type_info*`, for which one cannot supply an `operator<`. Possibly the sensible thing to do is to specialize `std::less<type_info*>`.

Comment: @ildjarn: Dietmar's question is 'why `type_info` has `before()` but not `operator<`'. Although what you say is correct, it doesn't answer his question. E.g. why can't I write `typeid(int) < typeid(long)`, instead I have to use `typeid(int).before(typeid(long))`.

Comment: @DietmarKühl: note that C++11 defines `type_index` that is just a wrapper for `const type_info*` with all the comparison operators defined.

Comment: @YakovGalka I looked at llvm implementation of `type_index`. The constructor takes reference of type_info but the internal private field which "holds" it is a pointer to type_info object. Why they use Pointer instead of Reference internally? https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/libcxx/include/typeindex#L57

Comment: Alternative `type_index` class impl which uses reference instead of pointer for `type_info` field https://gist.github.com/apivovarov/dcf94ea8861efd25f145650e2acbb2fb#file-typeindex-h-L57

Comment: @x4444: Using a reference disables copy-assignment, since you cannot change a reference after it's initialized. Looks like [`type_index` are meant to be `CopyAssignable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_index), therefore the second implementation you linked isn't standard conforming.

Comment: Should I use std::reference_wrapper? std::reference_wrapper is a class template that wraps a reference in a copyable, assignable object.

Comment: Looks like type_index class description defines the impl details - The relationship with type_info object is maintained through a pointer, therefore type_index is CopyConstructible and CopyAssignable.
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_index

Answer (score 1):

It gives an ordering.

That is required if you want to store values in some containers, like std::map.

Answer (score 1):

Think of it as less-than (`<`) operator for `type_info` objects. If you ever wanted to store in ordered collection - such a set of map - you can use it to make an appropriate comparator.  It's a reliable and preferred way, as opposed to, say, using type's name which might not be unique.