# SwigPyIterator value is always base class

Tags: python, c++, swig

I have classes A, B, C in C++. B and C are derived from A. And I have function in c++ returns vector of B and C: like `std::vector<A*> getAllObjects()`. I use swig to generate Python wrapper. Then I call getAllObjects() in Python as below:

```
objects = getAllObjects()
for obj in objects:
    if isinstance(obj, B):
        print("OK")
    elif isinstance(obj, C):
        print("OK")
```

The object I get from iterator is instance A, but it should be B or C. How to resolve the problem?

Comment: You could wrap functions, which consist of a `dynamic_cast` followed by comparison with `NULL`. Your python wrapped instances will never be instances of `B` or `C`.

Comment: @JensMunk, is it able to customze SwigPyIterator class to make the value return the type of derived classes (e.g. B or C) instead of base class (e.g. A)?

Comment: If `A` is an interface the different objects will of course behave as `B`and `C` respectivelt

Comment: No, I suggest you keep an identifier in your base class and downcast. You can easily wrap cast operations.

Comment: @JensMunk. Thanks. I understand it's easy to wrap cast. But I'm still curious if it's able to rewrite the function "_wrap_SwigPyIterator___next__"? How to rewrite a standard function generated by swig?

Comment: It is not difficult. Look into the source `std_vector.i`. You basically need to duplicate this and add the casts. The problem is how to make this generic. How to tell SWIG a list of possible types to cast to. I think a better solution is to make a specific `typemap` which returns a Python list containing multiple types. You could try casting to all types known to your library. There is a number of examples in the documentation for creating Python lists in an argout typemap. In this way you only need a single typemap. If you try to "remove" type-safety of `std::vector` it is a lot of work.

Comment: tell me more about the base class `A` - doe it have a pure virtual function or member that knows what the derived type is? Do you construct the instances within Python so that Python owns them all? There are neat solutions possible with python but they're specific to use cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need *something* more to go on than just a type hierarchy. Typically in a Python/SWIG scenario one of the following is sufficient:

1. a `virtual` function in the base class (i.e. RTTI)
2. some member variable or function that somehow identifies the most derived type of a given instance (e.g. a common pattern in C is to include the first field of a struct being some kind of type identifier).
3. some kind of hook at object creation time, for example if you know that all instances will be Python created/owned

I'm working to the assumption that the first type is sufficient, but even for other cases it's not hard to adapt.

To illustrate this I wrote the following header file:

```cpp
class A {
public:
  virtual ~A() {}
};

class B : public A {
};

class C: public A {
};
```

Given this header file, in pure C++ we can do the following, making use of RTTI:

```cpp
#include "test.hh"
#include <typeinfo>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  const auto& t1 = typeid(A);
  const auto& t2 = typeid(B);
  const auto& t3 = typeid(C);
  A *a = new A;
  A *b = new B;
  A *c = new C;
  const auto& at = typeid(*a);
  const auto& bt = typeid(*b);
  const auto& ct = typeid(*c);

  std::cout << t1.name() << "\n";
  std::cout << t2.name() << "\n";
  std::cout << t3.name() << "\n";
  std::cout << at.name() << "\n";
  std::cout << bt.name() << "\n";
  std::cout << ct.name() << "\n";
}
```

This illustrates that the problem we're trying to solve (what type is it really?) is in fact solvable using standard C++.

It's worth noting at this point that the problem is made slightly more complicated by the use of the `std::vector` iteration instead of just a function that returns a single `A*`. If we were just working with the return value of a function we'd write a `typemap(out)`. In the case of the `std::vector<A*>` however it is possible to customise the behaviour of the iteration returning and insert extra code to make sure Python is aware of the derived type and not just the base. SWIG has a type traits mechanism that most of the standard containers use to help them with common uses (e.g. iteration) without excessive duplication. (For reference this is in std_common.i I think).

So the basic plan is to hook into the output of the iteration process (`SwigPyIterator`, implemented as `SwigPyIteratorClosed_T` in this case), using the traits types that SWIG introduces for customising this. Inside that hook, instead of blindly using the SWIG type info for `A*` we'll use `typeid` to lookup the type dynamically in a `std::map`. This map is maintained internally to the module. If we find anything in that map we'll use it to return a more derived Python object, as a Python programmer would expect. Finally we need to register the types in the map at initialisation time.

So my interface ended up looking like this:

```cpp
%module test

%{
#include "test.hh"
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <typeindex> // C++11! - see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9859605/168175
%}

%include <std_vector.i>

%{
namespace {
  // Internal only, store the type mappings
  std::map<std::type_index, swig_type_info*> aheirarchy;
}

namespace swig {
  // Forward declare traits, the fragments they're from won't be there yet
  template <class Type> struct traits_from_ptr;
  template <class Type>
  inline swig_type_info *type_info();

  template <> struct traits_from_ptr<A> {
    static PyObject *from(A *val, int owner = 0) {
      auto ty = aheirarchy[typeid(*val)];
      if (!ty) {
        // if there's nothing in the map, do what SWIG would have done
        ty = type_info<A>();
      }
      return SWIG_NewPointerObj(val, ty, owner);
    }
  };
}
%}

%template(AList) std::vector<A*>;

%inline %{
const std::vector<A*>& getAllObjects() {
  // Demo only
  static auto ret = std::vector<A*>{new A, new B, new C, new C, new B};
  return ret;
}
%}

%include "test.hh"
%init %{
  // Register B and C here
  aheirarchy[typeid(B)] = SWIG_TypeQuery("B*");
  aheirarchy[typeid(C)] = SWIG_TypeQuery("C*");
%}
```

With the `%inline` function I wrote just to illustrate things that's enough to get things started. It allowed me to run the following test Python to demonstrate my solution:

```
from test import getAllObjects, A, B, C

objects = getAllObjects()
for obj in objects:
    print obj
    if isinstance(obj, B):
        print("OK")
    elif isinstance(obj, C):
        print("OK")
```

```
swig3.0 -c++ -python -Wall test.i
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall test_wrap.cxx -o  _test.so -shared -I/usr/include/python2.7/ -fPIC
python run.py 
<test.A; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'A *' at 0xf7442950> >
<test.B; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'B *' at 0xf7442980> >
OK
<test.C; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'C *' at 0xf7442fb0> >
OK
<test.C; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'C *' at 0xf7442fc8> >
OK
<test.B; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'B *' at 0xf7442f98> >
OK
```

Which you'll notice matched the types created in my dummy implementation of `getAllObjects`.

You could do a few things more neatly:

1. Add a macro for registering the types. (Or do it automatically some other way)
2. Add typemaps for regular returning of objects if needed.

And as I indicated earlier this isn't the only way to solve this problem, just the most generic.

Comment: That’s exactly what I expected. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve this is to use a macro in the .i file.

First, define a macro that can be used to check each type:

```
// dcast and pPyObj defined below...
%define %_container_typemap_dispatch(Type)
if (!dcast) {
    Type *obj = dynamic_cast<Type *>(*it);
    if (obj != NULL) {
        dcast = true;
        pPyObj = SWIG_NewPointerObj(%as_voidptr(obj), $descriptor(Type *), $owner | %newpointer_flags);
    }
}
%enddef
```

Then, define the function to map the output for the list or vector:

```
// LIST_TYPEMAP macro to create the proper wrappers in std::list<AbstractElement*>
// It works like %factory but inside std::list elements.
// It only works with types, not specific methods like %factory.
// Usage: container_typemap(OutputType, CastType1, CastType2, ...);
%define %container_typemap(ItemType, Types...)
%typemap(out) ItemType {
    PyObject *res = PyList_New($1.size());
    int i = 0;
    for (ItemType::iterator it = $1.begin();
         it != $1.end();
         ++it, ++i)
    {
        PyObject* pPyObj = NULL;
        bool dcast = false;
        %formacro(%_container_typemap_dispatch, Types)
        if (!dcast)
            // couldn't cast to proper type, use abstract type:
            pPyObj = SWIG_NewPointerObj(%as_voidptr(*it), $descriptor, $owner | %newpointer_flags);
        if (pPyObj != NULL)
            PyList_SetItem(res, i, pPyObj);
    }
    %set_output(res);
}
%enddef
```

Finally, use the container_typemap function to apply this to your objects:

```
%container_typemap(A, B, C);
```

Then, any time you want to add this for a new vector/list, just call:

```
%container_typemap(Base, Derived1, Derived2, Derived3);
```