# How do the type_info member functions work?

Tags: c++

I am currently learning Run-Time Type ID and the Casting Operator. I have some questions, can you help me to solve this doubts.

See the following code:

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <typeinfo>

 using namespace std;

 class base
 {

 };

 class derived
 {

 };

 int main()
 {
      cout<<typeid(char).name()<<endl;
      cout<<typeid(int).name()<<endl;
      cout<<typeid(float).name()<<endl;
      cout<<typeid(double).name()<<endl;
      cout<<typeid(base).name()<<endl;
      cout<<typeid(derived).name()<<endl;
 }
```

Output:

```
  c
  i
  f
  d
  4base
  7derived

  Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.238 s
  Press any key to continue.
```

Questions:

1. `typeid(base).name()` gives "`4base`"; what is `4` here and `typeid(derived).name()` gives "`7derived`"; what is `7` here?
2. Why do `typeid(char).name()` and other build in data types give the first letter only?
3. What is the `type_info::before()` function?

Thank you for your time and answer.

Comment: The name is implementation defined. They could return puppies if they want it to. If you want a readable name, for gcc, see http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/ext_demangling.html .

Comment: At first glance, 4 and 7 are the lengths of 'base' and 'derived' respectively. If you look at Andrei's link it looks like this length prefix is how string names are delimited in GCC's mangling scheme.

Comment: @AndreiDamian While true this doesn’t really explain *why*, which is a very valid question.

Comment: @KonradRudolph The answer to that is "because they can".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`type_info::name` returns an implementation-defined type name. It does not necessarily correspond to the actual spelling of these type names in code.

GCC and Clang return [mangled names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) because that is how these type names are represented internally. You can demangle them either manually by implementing the name mangling rules, or use existing tools such as `c++filt` or [the corresponding APIs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/ext_demangling.html).

`type_info::before` is not directly useful. Its value is essentially arbitrary, but *consistent*. This makes it usable for storing `type_info` objects in sorted containers, such as `std::set`, or use them as keys in `std::map`. `std::type_info::before` can here be used as the ordering relation. Alternatively, `type_info` could have overloaded `operator <` and that’s arguably what it *should* have done. [Even standard library authors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8682648/1968) don’t understand why this wasn’t done.

The following code shows an example where using `type_info::before` used to be necessary. Starting with C++11, it’s no longer necessary because you could use a [`type_index`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_index) key instead. Furthermore, this is obviously a contrived use of runtime type information: in real code you would not use `type_info` at all, you’d solve the problem with function overloading.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <typeinfo>

auto type_info_less = [](std::type_info const* a, std::type_info const* b) {
    return a->before(*b);
};

using type_name_map = std::map<
    std::type_info const*,
    char const*,
    decltype(type_info_less)
>;

auto const readable_type_names = type_name_map(
    {
        {& typeid(int), "int"},
        {& typeid(float), "float"},
        {& typeid(std::string), "std::string"},
        // ...
    },
    type_info_less
);

template <typename T>
auto type_name() {
    return readable_type_names.find(& typeid(T))->second;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << type_name<std::string>() << "\n";
    // Prints ”std::string”.
}
```

Note that we need to store pointers since `type_info` isn’t copyable or movable.

Comment: I will understand first two questions but I can't understand what is type_info::before, I searched In google about type_info::before but I can't get what they tell, so can you explain this.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I didn't get how type_info::before returns 0 or 1. In some websites they said that function returns upon  implementation’s collation order. But what is this?

Comment: @Srilakshmikanthanp It returns a `bool`, not 0 or 1. The “collation order” is a stupidly complicated way of saying that it functions like the `<` operator in C++. In other words, it can be used to sort `type_info` values (by some arbitrary ordering criterion … the *actual order* is unimportant, all that matters is that it’s consistent, because `std::map` uses such an order to find elements).